# Cool Ventilated and heated seats, can both options be used at once?

Tags: electrical, mercedes-benz, hvac, interior

In our S 350, both can be turned 'on' at the same time in the front and rear seats. Now is it that going to mess up the fan motor?

Comment: Which "motor" are you talking about? The engine which motivates the vehicle?

Comment: If the car allows it and the manual doesn't advise against it, it should be fine. Same is valid for almost everything on a car

Comment: Is the heat option electric resistance heaters ?

Comment: Just because you can does not mean you should. Kind of like a light socket, you can stick your finger in it but you **should not**. Even if it is not damaging to the "motor" it is not a smart thing to do.

Comment: @alaska man, some morons did that. I don’t have a definitive answer as to the repercussions on the seat cooling or heating system. Both rear and front seats have the option to heat and cool at the same moment. I would expect MB to fix this with a SW update. I asked the dealer they said not to worry about it unless I see a pop up on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is absolutely yes, (and there are various reasons why you might want to in certain conditions. If the air is warm but your seats are still cold, you may want to pop the seat heaters on for a short while to heat up. Or for people who have circulatory issues, a seat heater may be essential even though you want to keep cool air.)

All turning on options does is add some load to the vehicle, and all vehicles these days should be specced to cope with everything being turned on (or in some rare cases will inform you if the load is too high)

Of course, if you have a failing alternator or battery you may encounter issues, but those are the fault of the failing component. Extra load just exacerbates them.

Comment: I have no clue what that really did, why would anyone want to turn on the seat heater and cooler at the same time? This is not some function from the screen, it’s controlled by a separate button on the door panel in the front and rear, and unfortunately both heating and cooling buttons can be activated at once. 3 red leds and 3 blue leds (max heat and max cooling).

Comment: Don't me get wrong - I wouldn't use either ever, but I know folks who do like things the way they like them.

Comment: Let me rephrase. The seat has both a cooling and heating option, that we agree to. What we can do here is enable Heating and cooling together on the same seat. Now how does both heating and cooling at the same seat function?